# How to use Mapstruct with Ad Hoc Setters

Tags: java, mapping, domain-driven-design, mapstruct

I am trying to apply MapStruct to DDD. I created my entities with ad hoc setters like this:

```
@AllArgsContructor 
@NoArgsConstructor //necessary to MapStruct
@Getter
class Employee { 
    private String id; 
    private String name;
    
    public void updateName(String newName) {
        this.name = newName;
    }
    
}
```

and I have a `EmployeeDto` to send data to frontend API:

```
@Getter
@AlArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor //necessary to MapStruct
class EmployeeDto {
    private String name;
    private String id;
}
```

so, I am trying to use MapStruct to map, but it is not working because my ad hoc setter. How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: Small note. Starting from 1.4 the `@NoArgsConstructor` is no longer needed for MapStruct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement custom `AccessorNamingStrategy`. The way how to do it is well documented in section [13.1. Custom Accessor Naming Strategy](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_custom_accessor_naming_strategy) of a MapStruct documentation.

In your case it should look something like this:

```
public class CustomAccessorNamingStrategy extends DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy {
  @Override
  public boolean isSetterMethod(ExecutableElement method) {
    String methodName = method.getSimpleName().toString();
    return methodName.startsWith("update") && methodName.length() > 6;
  }

  @Override
  public String getPropertyName(ExecutableElement getterOrSetterMethod) {
    if (isSetterMethod(getterOrSetterMethod)) {
      String methodName = getterOrSetterMethod.getSimpleName().toString();
      return IntrospectorUtils.decapitalize(methodName.substring(6));
    } else {
      return super.getPropertyName(getterOrSetterMethod);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It just solved my problem. This class should be place in the same package of mapper class? I am new in programming

Comment: It doesn't matter where you place this class. You should expose it via a java SPI. It is explained in the section 13.1 (the link shared by @Tuom in the answer) for how to expose this class